# show results from multiple mysql tables using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have multiple mysql tables with the same structure. i am trying to show all the results from all tables with a single query. I have been searching online now for a few hours and this is what i came up with.

```
    $videos_query = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    table1.title,
                    table1.url,
                    table1.image,
                    table2.title,
                    table2.url,
                    table2.image,
                    table3.title,
                    table3.url,
                    table3.image
                 FROM
                    table1
                 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.url = table2.url
                 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.url = table3.url");
while($video_info = mysql_fetch_array($videos_query)){
```

However, using the above code in PHP im getting the error "Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given"

Comment: There isnt anything wrong with the query, in the while parameter you are comparing the resultset

Comment: @SashiKant Yes there is. `INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.url = table1.url` should probably be `INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.url = table2.url`

Comment: Perhaps you don't have the data in the tables.

Comment: @til_b: Ohhh I overlooked

Comment: still not working... the data in each table is diffrent so the url's should never =

Comment: Check my edited answer now - the second sql query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error in your sql query - `table1` has to be `table2`:

```
$videos_query = mysql_query("SELECT 
                    table1.title,
                    table1.url,
                    table1.image,
                    table2.title,
                    table2.url,
                    table2.image,
                    table3.title,
                    table3.url,
                    table3.image
                 FROM
                    table1
                 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.url = table2.url
                 INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.url = table3.url");

if (mysql_num_rows($videos_query) > 0) {
    while ($video_info = mysql_fetch_array($videos_query)) {
        // process your data here
    }
}
```

**If you want to do union selects:**

```
$videos_query = mysql_query("
  SELECT title, url, image
  FROM table1
  UNION
  SELECT title, url, image
  FROM table2
  UNION
  SELECT title, url, image
  FROM table3
");

if (mysql_num_rows($videos_query) > 0) {
    while ($video_info = mysql_fetch_array($videos_query)) {
        // process your data here
    }
}
```

Also, maybe you want to order by some column - so then add there `ORDER BY` + column_name.

Comment: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given

Answer (score 1):

change

```
 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.url = table1.url
```

to

```
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.url = table2.url
```

Comment: Basically, mysql_query requires two parameters 

mysql_query($query_string,$connection);

since only one param is given thus, it returns false instead of the result..

Refer:

[link](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_query.asp)

Comment: There is some error after you are running the query:

Try

echo mysql_error(); after mysql_query();

Answer (score 0):

While checking `ON` you are comparing  `table1.url = table1.url` which is incorrect.

Here is the correct code:

```
$videos_query = mysql_query("SELECT 
                table1.title,
                table1.url,
                table1.image,
                table2.title,
                table2.url,
                table2.image,
                table3.title,
                table3.url,
                table3.image
             FROM
                table1
             INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.url = table2.url
             INNER JOIN table3 ON table1.url = table3.url");
while($video_info = mysql_fetch_array($videos_query)){
```